# How draw an ECG wave with a static range in real time?

Tags: javascript, charts, canvasjs

I´m drawing an real time ECG Wave with CanvasJs ,all works good if I use the size of the array, but when I try to set that size for example 478 points this doesn't show the new data who is coming, the chart is static but I´m sending new data.

[image: ECG wave]

The code for that chart is the next one :

```
 maxDataLength = 478;
 dataLenght = 0;

   if (result.length !== maxDataLength) {
        for (var i = dataLength; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                data.push({
                    x: parseInt(result[i].valorx),
                    y: parseFloat(result[i].valory)
                });
               if (data.length > maxDataLength) {
               data.shift()}
            }
            dataLength = result.length;
            chart.render();
        }
  });
```

The problem is that the chart is not loading the new data.

The next code works for me :

```
dataLength = 0;

if (dataLength !== result.length) {
  for (var i = dataLength; i < result.length; i++) 
        {
            data.push({
                x: parseInt(result[i].valorx),
                y: parseFloat(result[i].valory)
            });
           if (data.length > result.length) {
           data.shift()}
        }
        dataLength = result.length;
        chart.render();
    }
});
```

But this graph show all the data of the array and looks awful, If you know how solve this task, please let me know.

Comment: Any errors on the JS console? You have a typo in your first code: `dataLenght`

Comment: In the console show me the next error : err_insufficient_resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you check this `maxDataLength` is before you do the loop:

```
if (result.length !== maxDataLength) {
```

How will this stop the loop when it gets to `maxDataLength`? Here is your working code, with typos fixed and one extra check in the `for` loop to compare the counter to `maxDataLength`:

```
maxDataLength = 478;
dataLength = 0;

if (dataLength !== result.length) {
    for (var i = dataLength; i < result.length && i <= maxDataLength; i++) {
        data.push({
            x: parseInt(result[i].valorx),
            y: parseFloat(result[i].valory)
        });
        if (data.length > result.length) {
            data.shift();
        }
        dataLength = result.length;
        chart.render();
    }
}
```

(This code was full of typos, I don't see that it would have worked in the first place.)